# Any ideas on making this function with jQuery shorter with an example

Tags: jquery

I have this working function called on the onShow with Superfish, it works fine, but I was thinking that it looked kinda bloated, I can read it. I'm an artist, so this stuff (years now) is still a brain gymnastic.

**If anyone has an example, no need to re-write, just an example of something similar to make this shorter or tips, that is all I want.**

```
    /** ==============================================================================
    * superfish edge detection
    =============================================================================== */
    function superfish_edge_detection() {

        var window_width = $(window).width();

        $('.nav-primary ul ul li').mouseover(function() { // yes, you must repeat this again

            if ( $( '#collapse-break-point' ).is( ':hidden' ) ) {

                var sub_menu_exist = $( this ).find( '.sub-menu' ).length;

                if ( sub_menu_exist > 0 ) {

                    var sub_menu_width = $( this ).find('.sub-menu').width();
                    var sub_menu_offset = $( this ).find('.sub-menu').parent().offset().left + sub_menu_width;

                    // if sub menu is off screen
                    if ((sub_menu_offset + sub_menu_width) >= window_width) {

                        var new_sub_menu_position = sub_menu_width + 0;
                        $(this).find('.sub-menu').css({
                            left: -new_sub_menu_position,
                            top: '0',
                        });

                    } // end is off screen
                    else if ( (sub_menu_offset + sub_menu_width ) <= window_width ) 
                    {

                        $(this).find('.sub-menu').css({
                            left: '100%'
                        });

                    } //end not off screen

                }

            } //if breakpoint is hidden
            else 
            {
                $( '.sub-menu' ).removeAttr( 'style' );

            } //breakpoint is not hidden

        }); //end mouseover function

    } //end superfish_edge_detection();
```

With the help of Santi (see answer, here is the revised):

http://jsbin.com/vabezipilu/edit?js

Comment: Instead of re-using `$( this ).find( '.sub-menu' )` over and over, set it to one variable, like `$submenu = $( this ).find( '.sub-menu' );`. You can then do `$submenu.width();`, `$submenu.css(...)`, etc. It will also substantially improve efficiency, as doing the `$(this).find` is actually looking for the element every single time.

Comment: So many calls to the same element `($this).find('.sub-menu')` is a drag for the script speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your sub-menu as one variable, not only to make the script shorter, but to improve speed. By using `.find()` over and over, JQuery has to keep looking for the element with each call.

```
function superfish_edge_detection() {

    var window_width = $(window).width();

    $('.nav-primary ul ul li').mouseover(function() { // yes, you must repeat this again

        var $sub_menu = $(this).find('.sub-menu');

        if ( $( '#collapse-break-point' ).is( ':hidden' ) ) {


            var sub_menu_exist = $sub_menu.length;

            if ( sub_menu_exist > 0 ) {

                var sub_menu_width = $sub_menu.width();
                var sub_menu_offset = $sub_menu.parent().offset().left + sub_menu_width;

                // if sub menu is off screen
                if ((sub_menu_offset + sub_menu_width) >= window_width) {

                    var new_sub_menu_position = sub_menu_width + 0;
                    $sub_menu.css({
                        left: -new_sub_menu_position,
                        top: '0',
                    });

                } // end is off screen
                else if ( (sub_menu_offset + sub_menu_width ) <= window_width ) 
                {

                    $sub_menu.css({
                        left: '100%'
                    });

                } //end not off screen

            }

        } //if breakpoint is hidden
        else 
        {
            $sub_menu.removeAttr( 'style' );

        } //breakpoint is not hidden

    }); //end mouseover function

} //end superfish_edge_detection();
```

Comment: This helped me tremendously with another one that I wrote which had to go the parent, find the children, etc., Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)